# Read file with Android, what is the expected path?

Tags: android

I am not having luck with this method, which is basically a hello world for printing file contents to the Android cat log.

```
  try {
            InputStream instream = openFileInput("inputFile.txt");
              InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
              BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
              String line;
              while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
              }
            instream.close();
          } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Using a default generated project with the Android Eclipse plugin, under what directory should this file exist? Any other considerations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will try to read the file `inputFile.txt` from your internal application data directory `/data/data/your.application.package/` (and will fail if it doesn't exist):

```
openFileInput("inputFile.txt");
```

To read a file from SD card you would do something like this:

```
new FileInputStream(Environement.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    .getAbsolutePath() + "/inputFile.txt")
```

Don't forget to set the SD card permission in your manifest then:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, I did a bit of reading and it looks like I want to use /res/raw, as this static data file would be distributed with the app rather than created by it (thus no /data/ directory)

Answer (score 0):

This file should exist in the apps local 'data' directory.  Does this file already exist?  Have you taken a look at the documentation for [file IO on Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)?